# To make dropdown selected while fetching dynamically

Tags: php, html

To make dropdown ticked while fetching dynamically from db.Fetch all values from db and list as dropdown.If the values from db matches particular value make that dropdown selected

```
<select id="designation" name="designation"> 
<? while($role=mysql_fetch_array($sql_role)){ 
  if ($role['role'] == $desig ) echo $selected="selected"; else  $selected=" ";?>
  <option <?=$selected?>>Select</option>
  <option value="<?=$role['id']?>" 
  <?=$selected?> >
  <?=$role['role']?>
  </option>
   <? } ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you make the following changes and try. You can totally eliminate the intermediate variable storage. Just print selected if the condition matches. And also you should just put that default select option outside the while loop.

```
<select id="designation" name="designation"> 
    <option>Select</option>
    <? while($role=mysql_fetch_array($sql_role)){ ?>
        <option value="<?=$role['id']?>" <? if ($role['role'] == $desig ) echo "selected='selected'"?> ><?=$role['role']?></option>
    <? } ?>
</select>
```

Comment: So far the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

try to avoid short scripts in php like this

```
 <select id="designation" name="designation"> 
         <? while($role=mysql_fetch_array($sql_role)){ 
             <option <?php  if ($role['role'] == $desig ) { ?> selected <?php } ?> ><?php echo $role['role']; ?></option>

        <? } ?></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are echoing `$selected` in your check. I also recommend not to use php short tags because it may be deprecated in future PHP versions.

I recommend this code:

```
$html = '<select id="designation" name="designation">';
$html .= '<option>Select</option>';
while($role = mysql_fetch_array($sql_role))
{
    $selected = ($role['role'] == $desig) ? ' selected' : '';

    $html .= '<option value="'. $role['id'] .'"'. $selected .'>'. $role['role'] .'</option>';
}

$html .= '</select>';
echo $html;
```

Don not forget to assign `$desig` ;-).